# Trying to change default colours when plotting in spyder 2.7

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, spyder

I've a program that takes 300 particles and moves each of them through 300 steps. Each time each of these particles is stepped forward, my program plots the position of the particle. I need my program to be able to cycle through like 5 different colours when plotting the 900 different points to make them easier to make out. Any ideas how to set the colours to cycle through? My code at the moment is contained below:

```
import numpy as np 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q = np.zeros((300,300))

p = np.zeros((300,300))

mu = 1

R = 1.0/np.sqrt(2.0)

theta = R*2*np.pi

q[:,0] = np.random.uniform(-20.0, 20.0, 300)

p[:,0] = np.random.uniform(-20.0, 20.0, 300)

N = len(q)

for i in range(1,N):  

    q[:,i] = q[:,i-1]*np.cos(theta) + p[:,i-1]*np.sin(theta) + mu*np.sin(q[:,i-1])*np.sin(theta)

    p[:,i] = p[:,i-1]*np.cos(theta) - q[:,i-1]*np.sin(theta) + mu*np.sin(q[:,i-1])*np.cos(theta)


plt.plot(q, p, "o", markersize = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
colors = ('black', 'blue', 'red', 'green','orange')
n_colors = len(colors)

for offset, color in enumerate(colors):
    plt.plot(q[:,offset::n_colors], p[:,offset::n_colors],
             marker="o", markersize = 0.1, color=color)
```

the image getting from that is not very informative, tough. but maybe you can start something useful from here...

if you do not want the points to be linked, try a [scatter plot](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/scatter/)

```
for offset, color in enumerate(colors):
    plt.scatter(q[:,offset::n_colors], p[:,offset::n_colors],
                marker="o", color=color, alpha=.4, s=1)
```

which plots:

[image: scatter plot]

Comment: Is there anyway to stop them from joining up and just have the points plotted without the lines?

Comment: @akearney added scatter plot example, maybe that is closer to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you issue the plot command inside your loop for each step.

First create a cyclic iterator with the colorization command:

```
import itertools
col = itertools.cycle(['g', 'b', 'r', 'k'])
```

Then change your code:

```
for i in range(1,N):  

    q[:,i] = q[:,i-1]*np.cos(theta) + p[:,i-1]*np.sin(theta) + mu*np.sin(q[:,i-1])*np.sin(theta)

    p[:,i] = p[:,i-1]*np.cos(theta) - q[:,i-1]*np.sin(theta) + mu*np.sin(q[:,i-1])*np.cos(theta)

    plt.plot(q[:,i], p[:,i], marker = "o", markersize = 0.1, color = next(col))
```

Comment: Do you know how I could plot single points rather than having them joined up by lines?